# Getting value dynamically from URL React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem where I need to get some value from URL however I need to get this value in the first component to be rendered so this component is not inside any Route or something and I guess in this way I am not able to use `useParams` hook.

`const bookSlug = location.pathname.split('/')[3];`

I am getting the value from url like this right now and I don't think that this is a good way.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

**Getting path:**

in this case we use `useLocation` and location object is returned to us

```js
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  search: '?some=search-string',
  hash: '#howdy',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```

**Getting query string properties:**

in this case we use `useParams`. this hook returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters.

I your case `useLocation` would do your job.

Comment: I am currently using useLocation() with the code ```const location = useLocation(); const bookSlug = location.pathname.split('/')[3];```

Comment: I suppose its the only way